# Flutter Error: Your project requires a higher compileSdkVersion

Tags: android, flutter

when I clone and run the project, it shows: Your project requires a higher compileSdkVersion.So I did what it said, which to change:

```
android {                                                                                                                    │
│   compileSdkVersion 31                                                                                                       │
│ }
```

> in android\app\build.gradle. But then it show another error:  failed
> to install
> D:\programming\Flutter_Projects\mi_card_flutter\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk:
> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE] Error launching
> application on AOSP on IA Emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error means that there is no enough space to install the app, try to clean some space by uninstalling unwanted apps or removing unwanted files from the physical device or the emulator you are trying to run on it.

Comment: but my D driver has 279GB free left...

Comment: It is not about the machine you are developing with, it's about the physical device or emulator you are trying to run on it.

Comment: This comment saved me because I thought my Flutter app was not installing due to a low API version but there simply wasn't sufficient storage, lol